How can I change Materials for Duplicated Objects with Animation?
I have duplicated an object with animation and changed the material for the second one (the duplicate). I have already clicked Make Single User for them, but the original object still changes the material along with the duplicate. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Hello and welcome. Did you duplicate using Shift+D or Alt+D?

By default the duplicated object will keep the same material, if you want the duplicated object to have a brand new material, go into the Preferences > Editing > Copy on Duplicate and enable Material:

That said in your case you just need to create a new material for your duplicated object:

Note that if you want your duplicated object to still be linked to the original one but give it a new material, choose the Object option in the Material panel, the objects will still be linked but they will have their own material:

